# Copying from one file to another using nano editor

Tags: linux, unix, nano

How do I copy a few lines from one file to another file using the nano editor?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you are in pure console mode and can't use the mouse to copy/paste:

1. Launch nano in multi-buffer mode (nano -F)
2. CTRL-^ to start your selection.
3. Arrow key around until you cover all the text you want to copy.
4. ESC-^ to copy the selection into the cut buffer
5. CTRL-R ESC-F to open a file into a new buffer
6. CTRL-U to paste in the opened file

NOTE: To switch between buffers use either ESC-< and ESC-> or ESC-, and ESC-. (the later is helpful if < and > use the same key on your keyboard layout)

An alternative to 2-4 above is to go to the line(s) you want to copy and CTRL-K to delete them, pressing CTRL-K repeatedly to multiple lines to the buffer.  When you've cut all the lines you want to copy, CTRL-Y to re-paste them back into the current buffer.  Then continue with step 5.

ALT or any other keys with [Meta-key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key) behaviour could also be used instead of ESC in these commands.

Comment: What key is ^ for steps 2 and 4? And what keys are 'ESC-<' and 'ESC->'? Is it Escape and then hyphen and then shift comma / period all together?

Comment: The instructions above are generally correct, but on step five skip the ESC-F in order to open the second file into it's _own_ area. Following the instructions above (and typing ESC-F) will instead insert the second file _into_ the first file (which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Additionally, on some systems (such as on Raspbian), you may be able to use the 'Alt' key instead of the 'Escape' key. (In some discussion about Nano, the Escape key and Alt key are referred to as the 'Meta' key).

Answer (score 19):

Copy text from one file to another with nano text editor

Note: To help you understand better, we will use a

source file: `/var/named/athens.local`

destination file: `/var/named/patra.local`

1. Open the destination file (the file that want to paste the text  into), by using nano's multiple buffer.

`nano -F destination_file`

So we have:

```
nano -F /var/named/patra.local
```

2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>.
3. From inside nano editor, open the source file

   /var/named/athens.local
4. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+^ (this will enable the "mark set" mode)
5. Select your text.
6. When you have marked all the text you want, copy the text to

clipboard by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+^

```
Note: Now your text is in clipboard.

Note: In help file you will see the Alt+^ described as M-^.
```

7. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, to close the source file (`/var/named/athens.local`).

   Now we will see the destination file (`/var/named/patra.local`).

Move the cursor to the place you want to paste the copied text (which is

in buffer, don't forget that).

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, to paste the text.

You are done.

Comment: I like this answer better than the accepted answer because you explain step by step what is actually happening. Thank you.

Comment: This is extremely clear thank you. To anyone else wondering - the ^ symbol really does mean Shift + 6. So to set the mark it's Control + Shift + 6 on a Windows / Linux keyboard. And to save to clipboard it's Alt + Shift + 6.